# How do I delete all packages which match a certain pattern?

Tags: apt, aptitude

I want to uninstall libreoffice. This program consists of about three dozen modules. Ideally, they could be removed with:

```
aptitude remove libreoffice3.6* libreoffice-debian-menus libobasis3.6-*
```

but that fails with

```
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "libreoffice3.6*"
```

etc.

How do I delete a set of packages by pattern?

PS: I'm happy about answers with use `dpkg` or `apt`, too

Comment: Are you trying to know the answer about *certain pattern* or happy with the removal of LibreOffice components?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to uninstall LibreOffice?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180403/how-to-uninstall-libreoffice) The answer is probabaly: this only works for 3.6 and you are not using 3.6 :-)

Comment: I'm using libreoffice as an example because it contains so many parts. But I had the same problem with the kernel (cleaning up old versions)

Comment: @AaronDigulla Yes, but old versions of the kernel at least have some potential usage scenarios, unlike the "loathsome culprit and huge waste of disk space" that is directly mentioned in this question.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

1. Use `apt-get` or `apt`, (not `aptitude`), and use anchored regular expressions.
2. In a regular expression, `.` mean any character, and `*` means zero or more times. So the expression `libreoffice.*` matches any package name containing the string `libreoffice`, followed by any number of characters. You must anchor the regular expression with `^` (to match the beginning of the string) or `$` (to match the end of the string) or both, otherwise, the regular expression will not be recognised by APT.
3. Surround the regular expression with single quotes to avoid the shell interpreting the asterisk.

#### Example:

To remove all packages with a name that starts with `libreoffice`, run:

```
sudo apt remove '^libreoffice.*$'
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Interestingly enough, it also works with the pattern `libreoffice*` (i.e. glob style patterns) which confuses me a bit because either of them shouldn't work :-)

Comment: For those who want to test this, use the option `--dry-run` to see what would be deleted without any changes to the system.

Comment: apt-get is pretty bad handling regular expressions too, compare both solutions in [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44989/41104).

Comment: To make it clear, `apt` uses POSIX regular expressions. From `man apt-get` (Debian Jessie): "If no package matches the given expression and the expression contains one of '.', '?' or '*' then it is assumed to be a POSIX regular expression..."

Comment: I've updated the answer to say that the regular expression must be anchored. From the man page: "Fallback to regular expressions is deprecated in APT 2.0, has been removed in `apt(8)`, except for anchored expressions, and will be removed from `apt-get(8)` in a future version. Use `apt-patterns(5)` instead."

Comment: `apt-get` does seem to support globs (`sudo apt remove 'libreoffice*'` notice the lack of a dot), but I can't seem to find documentation about this. @AaronDigulla

Answer (score 12):

An alternative is:

```
dpkg -l | grep libreoffice | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n1 echo
```

This will list out all the packages matching `libreoffice`. When you've confirmed that they're all the ones you wish to get rid of, run the following command... *with caution*:

```
dpkg -l | grep libreoffice | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n1 sudo apt-get purge -y
```

The idea:

1. Get the system to list out all installed packages
2. Filter to show only the ones matching `libreoffice`
3. Filter to show only the column with the package name
4. Run the purge command on each of those packages

Comment: maybe you could suggest adding the `-p` option so that `xargs` will prompt for confirmation before executing each command constructed, or first checking with `echo` instead of `sudo apt-get purge`

Comment: @Zanna `-p` would help, but it wouldn't be a one-shot command. I did use echos to test what I was getting before running the command, so that's worth recommending.

Comment: I can give you +1 now you made it safer :)

Comment: I think the `-n1` is good for the `echo` but you have to remove it from the purge; otherwise, dependency order (a depends on b, tries to delete b first) might break the purge.

Comment: Your solution is the best I've found until now, thank you.

Comment: This is great! However, for those who, like myself, are having issues with apt itself, dpkg may be used as the final command, like so: `dpkg -l | grep libreoffice | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n1 sudo dpkg -r` (or with `sudo dpkg -P` to purge instead of remove).

Answer (score 6):

Aptitude has support for global patterns, and another pretty cool matches like this:

```
aptitude remove '?and(?name(libreoffice), name(3.6), ~i)' libreoffice-debian-menus
```

This will match any package that has in it's name `libreoffice` and `3.6` and also it's installed (that's what the `~i` stands for.

Comment: I think `apt-get` and `apt` have support for this now.

Answer (score 4):

2023 solution

`sudo apt remove 'libreoffice*' -y`

(The `-y` flag skips the "are you sure?" prompt)

Comment: Thanks. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to remove many files having the same prefix, I find brace expansion very handy:

```bsh
sudo apt remove libreoffice-l10n-{bg,ca,cs,da,de,en-za,es,fr,hu,id,ja,ko,nb,nl,pl,pt,ru,sv,th,tr,uk,vi,zh-cn,zh-tw}
```

I used this command to remove all the language packs that I never use. Yes, with a regex you can tell which one to keep, and delete the others. Anyway I like this because it's easy to remember, and it works also with many bash commands.