# Using apt to remove many packages by mask

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, uninstall

I'm new in linux. Trying to remove libreoffice from by xubuntu 20.04. Libreoffice was installed with xubuntu.
I execute many variants:

```
sudo apt remove 'libreoffice\*'
sudo apt remove 'libreoffice*'
sudo apt remove 'libreoffice.*'
```

In all cases I got error:

```
E: Unable to locate package libreoffice.*  <result depends on input>
```

**What I tried:**

but next solution shows how use `apt-get` instead of `apt`.

https://askubuntu.com/a/277771/906861

**My questions are:**

1. how to specify mask for `apt remove` command?
2. how to remove correctly libreoffice using apt?
3. what if I use `apt-get` for this case?

Comment: Depends upon how you installed LibreOffice, which you have not mentioned in your question. Please do so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem using wildcard with apt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218814/problem-using-wildcard-with-apt) and [How to uninstall LibreOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180403/how-to-uninstall-libreoffice)

Comment: @user535733 I did not instelled `libreoffice`. This was installed with xubuntu

Comment: That's critical information, and needs to be in your question above!