# How to uninstall libreoffice 32bit from my 64bit system

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, libreoffice, 32-bit

```
karl@karl-Dell-Precision-M3800:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice5.2*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libreoffice5.2-base:i386' for glob 'libreoffice5.2*'
Note, selecting 'libreoffice5.2-impress:i386' for glob 'libreoffice5.2*'
Note, selecting 'libreoffice5.2-stdlibs:i386' for glob 'libreoffice5.2*'
Note, selecting 'libreoffice5.2-en-us:i386' for glob 'libreoffice5.2*'
Note, selecting 'libreoffice5.2-ure:i386' for glob 'libreoffice5.2*'
Note, selecting 'libreoffice5.2-debian-menus' for glob 'libreoffice5.2*'
Note, selecting 'libreoffice5.2-writer:i386' for glob 'libreoffice5.2*'
Note, selecting 'libreoffice5.2-calc:i386' for glob 'libreoffice5.2*'
Note, selecting 'libreoffice5.2-dict-en:i386' for glob 'libreoffice5.2*'
Note, selecting 'libreoffice5.2-dict-es:i386' for glob 'libreoffice5.2*'
Note, selecting 'libreoffice5.2-dict-fr:i386' for glob 'libreoffice5.2*'
Note, selecting 'libreoffice5.2-draw:i386' for glob 'libreoffice5.2*'
Note, selecting 'libreoffice5.2-math:i386' for glob 'libreoffice5.2*'
Note, selecting 'libreoffice5.2:i386' for glob 'libreoffice5.2*'
Package 'libreoffice5.2-stdlibs:i386' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libobasis5.2-core:i386 : Depends: libreoffice5.2-ure:i386 (>= 5.2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libreoffice5.2-ure:i386 (<= 5.2.2.2-2) but it is not going to be installed
 master-pdf-editor3:i386 : Depends: libqt4-svg:i386 (>= 4.6.4) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libqt4-network:i386 (>= 4.6.4) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (>= 4.6.4) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libqtgui4:i386 (>= 4.8.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I accidentally installed 32bit instead. Now it's refusing to remove. I would prefer not to run `sudo apt-get -f install` as it touches other stuff.

Comment: Try with `sudo dpkg --purge libreoffice5.2*`, I am not sure if it helps but to try it costs only 30 seconds of your time...

Answer (score 0):

Type the following in terminal to remove libreoffice.

`sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*`

`sudo apt-get clean`

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

Hope this helps.

Also see answers for this question for further detail. [uninstall Libreoffice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180403/how-to-uninstall-libreoffice)