# How to completelly reinstall LibreOffice?

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 (fresh installation), but I have lot of problems with LibreOffice. I am not more specific, as these problems seems of various nature, with windows not updating, crashing and so on.
I had no problems in 14.04.

So, I would like to "reset" LibreOffice and reinstall it. What is the best way to reinstall all the LibreOffice packages in Ubuntu 16.04?

**UPDATED**: I did lookup for all LibreOffice packages in Synaptic and "purged" them before reinstalling, but I still have problems as you can see from the following screenshot (editing math formula is not the only problem, but it is the most repeatable one, so I am using it as a benchmark of things working or not)
[image: Screenshot of editing formula]

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1143/how-can-i-uninstall-software

Comment: And this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application

Comment: @CristianaNicolae: yup, but libreoffice is a miriade of packages.. my question is how to be sure I am removing all the packages involved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't encountered this problem myself, so I didn't have a chance to experiment the following solution myself. But, according to this [blog post](http://anglehit.com/how-to-remove-libreoffice-from-ubuntu-linux-the-command-line-way/), this [AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/180407/146105) and even this [forum thread](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/22466/how-to-uninstall-libreoffice-on-ubuntu-in-terminal/), the solution to your problem would be as follows:

Open Terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Thank you. I solved purging again libreoffice and installing the debs directly from the LibreOffice site.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reinstalling LibreOffice, but that solution wasn't working for me. I checked my `/tmp/` directory and it turns out there was this frozen file that I had to remove:

```
/tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_SingleOfficeIPC_b0dc85e3bd564c5817d1b2a7798830
```