# How do I update to the newest LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice

There's a newer version of LibreOffice Writer available than the one I installed with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

1. How do I install it? It appears to have 46 separate files or packages. Is there a single technique or command that will install it in one swoop?
2. After installation, will it continue to operate with the older remaining parts of LibreOffice remaining on my computer (spreadsheet, presentation software, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

The latest LibreOffice is available in the Snap Store, you can either install it from Ubuntu Software (just search for "libreoffice") or just `sudo snap install libreoffice`.

[image]

This will still keep your older version of LibreOffice around, but you can remove those if you want:

- [How to uninstall LibreOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180403/how-to-uninstall-libreoffice)