# Can't uninstall certain default softwares from ubuntu software GUI

Tags: software-center, uninstall, libreoffice

I am trying to uninstall "Libreoffice", "onboard", "onlineaccounts" etc. from ubuntu software center GUI after authenticating remove these are removed from there for short time after some time they appear back. Kindly tell me how to uninstall these items completely and delete there data as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the apt command. It will look something like this

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Here is the link to the Ubuntu forum for more detail.   [How to uninstall LibreOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180403/how-to-uninstall-libreoffice)

Answer (score 0):

Even if the Ubuntu software center GUI is a very pretty eye candy i suggest learning your way around the Linux cli because there lays the true power of this operating system.
You can use the purge command from the apt package manager to permanently delete some pack and its dependencies.
For example for libre office you should type:
`sudo apt purge libreoffice`

Comment: `libreoffice` is just a met-package. Removing/purging it won't actually uninstall any of the LO components. `sudo apt purge libreoffice*` will remove everything with libreoffice in its name.

Comment: correct forgot about the globbing sorry

Answer (score 0):

Or if you are uncomfortable with terminal you can also remove them using Ubuntu Software->Installed->Remove. You might need to retry it a couple of times if it fails[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84LZn.png)