# LibreOffice Writer 5.4.2.2 not working on Ubuntu 16.4.3

Tags: libreoffice, crash

EDIT II: Writer crashes LO. Calc and Impress work fine, no issues. This begun after a botched upgrade. I have tried: uninstalling and installing writer again, reinstalling LO from scratch. Nothing works. Starting LO from the terminal doesn't produce any error msg.

Here are the details of the internal error box from Ubuntu

[image: Ubuntu internal error msg]

Any ideas how I can solve it? Will upgrading to 17.04 do?

EDIT: Following the instructions of another use, I opened LibreOffice from the terminal. It crashes when either attempting to create a new document or opening an old one, but there's no error msg. in the terminal.

Comment: Check this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/180403/how-to-uninstall-libreoffice#180407

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what happens when you try to open Writer? Do you get an error message? Does the program freeze? It's hard to help people with computer issues when there are no details.

Comment: When use Calc, everything works fine. If I try to open a text file or create a new document, LibreOffice crashes. The error message I get is of executable path.

Comment: Open a terminal, leave the terminal open then type `libreoffice` this just runs libreoffice from a terminal instead of from the menu.  Now try to open or create a new LibreOffice Writer document  does this work?  If not the terminal may have some error messages that will help us work out what is going wrong.  Edit this question to include the error messages and we may be able to help.

Comment: Have you considered simply using the [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libreoffice&searchon=names) available in the Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: @WarrenHill First, thanks. I followed your instructions, LO crashes when either attempting to create a new document or opening an old one, but there's no error msg. in the terminal.

Comment: Like Elder Geek suggests, if the LO packages from the LO-PPA don't work for you, you may want to “purge” that PPA and revert to the LO packages provided by Canonical in Ubuntu's default repositories. Possible duplicate of [How can PPAs be removed?](/q/307/175814)

Comment: Based on the error in your image, it looks like an issue with the Java support. Here's a related post: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/120488/libreoffice-writer-will-not-launch/

Comment: @ElderGeek Thanks a lot! The answer in the link you provided did the job!

Comment: @MaxB based on your response I've written an answer. Always glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't appear as if upgrading to 17.04 will solve your issue as the problem has been [reported with 17.04 as well](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/120447/libreoffice-base-crashes-on-32bit-linux/) (at least the 32-bit release anyway). There are several approaches you could take to solve this problem.

One approach would be to purge the PPA as suggested by [David Foerster](https://askubuntu.com/users/175814/david-foerster) [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963690/libreoffice-writer-5-4-2-2-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-4-3/965117#comment1543852_963690) and installing the version from the repositories as mentioned in my comment [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963690/libreoffice-writer-5-4-2-2-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-4-3?noredirect=1#comment1543073_963690)

Another approach would be to simply Go to LibreOffice->Tools->Options-> Advanced and untick the box under Java options shown here:

[image: UseJRE]

There is also a kernel based workaround that is reported to work with both 16.04 and 17.04 related to these bug reports ([1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1699772), [2.](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=108619))

This workaround is to add the kernel option `stack_guard_gap=1` to your boot parameters. Instructions on how to add a boot parameter are found [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter)

Sources:

https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/120488/libreoffice-writer-will-not-launch/

https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/120447/libreoffice-base-crashes-on-32bit-linux/

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1699772

https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=108619

https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/102036/writer-crashes/