# Being stopped on LibreOffice when trying to update Lubuntu

Tags: package-management, lubuntu, dpkg, dependencies, libreoffice

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:6.3.5) but 1:6.3.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libreoffice-help-common : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.3.5-0ubuntu0.19.10.1) but 1:6.3.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libreoffice-help-en-us : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.3.5-0ubuntu0.19.10.1) but 1:6.3.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libreoffice-style-breeze : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.3.5-0ubuntu0.19.10.1) but 1:6.3.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libreoffice-st yle-colibre : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.3.5-0ubuntu0.19.10.1) but 1:6.3.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libreoffice-style-tango : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.3.5-0ubuntu0.19.10.1) but 1:6.3.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Every time I go to uninstall it a different way I get the same error with unmet dependencies. I tried a ton of things, namely everything in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180403/how-to-uninstall-libreoffice) and others like it.

```
~$ sudo apt-get update 
Hit:1 us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease 
Hit:2 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease 
Hit:3 us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease 
Hit:4 us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease 
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: Please provide release details as this could be a release/sources issue (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libreoffice).  Also when you `sudo apt update` to update your sources list, was anything unusual there? (or missing, eg. -updates)

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:        19.10
Codename:       eoan


Nothing unusual from the update, it says everything completes there. It's only when I upgrade.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion "sudo apt --fix-broken install"?  I would also try the classic "sudo dpkg --configure -a" After that then I would uninstall or purge it and then upgrade and reinstall it. BUT when something like this fails it could mean there are other issues.  Make sure you have good backups before you try the upgrade.

Comment: Was `eoan-updates` listed in the `sudo apt update`?   Sorry if I was unclear, the link I provided showed the packages is found in `eoan-updates` yet the package you have installed is from `eoan`  (ie. you have original and not the updated package).

Comment: ~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done


I have also ran the suggested command already and I get similar errors pertaining to libreoffice. 

And as far as the packages go, I'm trying to update them but get stopped at this point each time I go to update.

Comment: Did you use any ppa to update libreoffice?

Comment: I don't know what ppa is I'm sorry.

Comment: Please add `apt-cache policy libreoffice-core libreoffice-common` to your question.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libreoffice-common https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libreoffice-core https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu , and have you tried the `sudo apt -f install` asked earlier?  (normally `sudo apt update` is done first, not subsequent to other commands yet you listed it second, is there a reason?)